# spring batch conversion from db2 to oracle

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-batch

I'm converting some data from a DB2 table to Oracle table. I'm having the following problem and I have a solution for it but I was wondering if there is a better alternative?

My problem is the following:

> DB2 table has all the records that need to be converted to Oracle but
>   the Oracle table has a column which holds an auto-generated id from
>   another Oracle table.

```
DB2 customer table --> Oracle customer table 
Db2-Name  --> Oracle-Name 
Db2-age --> Oracle-age
```

> BUT

`Oracle customer table` has an phone field for customer that must come from `Oracle-phone table`.
My solution is to create a `temp customer table` in Oracle and convert all the DB2 data to it using spring batch and after run another spring batch with a join between the `customer temp table` and `phone table` and insert the data into `Oracle-customer table`. 
Is there a better way to do that? for example is there a way that I can join customer table from DB2 with Oracle phone table. taking into consideration that I'm not the DB admin.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An alternative approach could be to use an `ItemProcessor` to enrich the data as it is read from the DB2 customer table. The `ItemProcessor` would lookup the phone number and add it to the object before it's written.

Comment: @MichaelMinella thanks for your reply! I'm a beginner in spring batch so I was hoping ithat you can direct me to a tutorial or example for using itemprocessor to look up from other tables

Comment: I don't have an example of that specific use case.  However, you can read about the `ItemProcessor` interface in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemProcessor.html